# Load data to amazon RDS/SQL from S3

Tags: mysql, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I know this is not a programming question but I would really appreciate for the help.

I am trying to transfer files from s3 bucket to the Amazon RDS mysql database particularly to table say 'test'. I am doing this first time and don't know how to approach to it. 
I tried in the following way:

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-s3 ^
--allocated-storage 250 ^ 
--db-instance-identifier myidentifier ^
--db-instance-class db.m4.large ^
--engine mysql ^
--master-user-name masterawsuser ^
--master-user-password masteruserpassword ^
--s3-bucket-name mybucket ^
--s3-ingestion-role-arn arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/rolename ^
--s3-prefix bucketprefix ^
--source-engine mysql ^
--source-engine-version 5.6.27
```

The AWS Console is showing `"incompatible restore" for "myidentifier"`. I don't know how to resolve it.

And I am wondering by the above code, will the data gets load in the desired table("test")?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to restore SQL as an RDS instance. 
RDS instances are managed database servers which you then create databases within. 
You should create an RDS instance then load your SQL code using MySQL command line tools. 
If you are migrating from an existing database server also have a look at AWS DMS.